# Is it possible to automatically deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk on PR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to deploy PR to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?
I want to test out the PR branch first before merging it to my master branch.
Is there a simpler way than to set up the whole environment from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, for that you would setup CICD pipeline, with [CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome.html) (CP). The CP would have source action set to your repo master or feature  branch to trigger CP.

CP supports Elastic Beanstalk (EB) through [EB deploy action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/integrations-action-type.html#w2aac11b9c13c15).